# Why is it showing different images in 4d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a 4D array for a bunch of 3D images. I can load the image and show the image correctly, but after storing it to the 4D array and show the image from the array, it shows gibberish.

I tried to compare if the image loaded and the one read from the 4D array is equal, and it prints True.

```
import os
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

IMG_PATH = '32x32'
img_paths = glob(os.path.join(IMG_PATH, '*.jpg'))
images = np.empty((len(img_paths), 32, 32, 3))
for i, path_i in enumerate(img_paths):
    img_i = np.array(Image.open(path_i))
    Image.fromarray(img_i, 'RGB').show() # showing correct image
    images[i] = img_i
    Image.fromarray(images[i], 'RGB').show() # showing gibberish
    print(np.array_equal(img_i, images[i])) # True
    if i == 0:
        break
```

I expect to show the exact same image as I run `images[i] = img_i`.

Comment: probably a type problem. try np.empty((len(img_paths), 32, 32, 3),dtype=np.uint8)

Comment: `dtype=np.uint8` is probably more likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is performing a cast:

```
images[i] = img_i
```

Since `images.dtype == np.float64`, but `img_i.dtype` is *probably* `np.uint8`.

---

You can catch this type of mistake by specifying a casting rule:

```
np.copy_to(images[i], img_i, casting='no')
# TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('uint8') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'no'
```

---

You can fix this by allocating the array with the right type:

```
images = np.empty((len(img_paths), 32, 32, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Or you can let numpy do the allocation for you, but this will temporarily use almost twice the memory:

```
images = np.stack([
    Image.open(path_i)
    for path_i in img_paths
], axis=0)
```